# Inlining data-urls with Stylus and Gulp

Tags: css, gulp, stylus

Currently I have a stylus file that imports another stylus file. This second file uses the URL function like this, and I want it to be inlined (e.g. to a base 64 data-url). However this isn't working when run through my gulp pipeline

**lines.styl**:

```
vertical-img = 'vertical.svg';
@import "../tree";
```

**tree.styl**

```
background-image: url(vertical-img)
```

---

What I want to get as a result is:

```
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg>[...]</svg>');
```

But I get this:

```
background-image: url("vertical.svg")
```

And my gulpfile is as follows:

```
return gulp.src('src/css/*/*.styl')
    .pipe(gstylus({
        set: ['resolve url']
    }))
    .pipe(rename(function (file) {
        file.dirname = "";
        file.extname = ".css";
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(DEST))
```

Basically it seems like the 'resolve url' option isn't being passed to stylus. I'm aware that I need it, since it says in the [Stylus Docs](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/import.html) that:

> By default Stylus doesn’t resolve the urls in imported .styl files, so if you’d happen to have a foo.styl with @import "bar/bar.styl" which would have url("baz.png"), it would be url("baz.png") too in a resulting CSS.
>
> But you can alter this behavior by using --resolve-url (or just -r) CLI option to get url("bar/baz.png") in your resulting CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct option for image inlining is `url` (not `resolve url`) see http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/functions.url.html. To use it in `gulp-stylus` you should pass `url` option to options object (see https://github.com/jenius/accord/blob/master/docs/stylus.md#url). For example:

```
return gulp.src('src/css/*/*.styl')
.pipe(gstylus({
    url: { name: 'url', limit: false }
}))
.pipe(rename(function (file) {
    file.dirname = "";
    file.extname = ".css";
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest(DEST))
```

Comment: I thought the documentation was pretty unclear on the url function, so thanks!